# Convert a Collection to Map<String,Collection<String>> using java 8 streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I am looking to convert a `Collection<Placement>` to `Map<String, Collection<String>>` using java streams, where the `Placement` class is as below

```
public class Placement {

   private String id;

   /* Links two placements, may be same for atleast 2 placements. */
   private String futureLinkId;
}
```

The key for the map is future link id and the values are placement ids. For example if there are 2 placements 
`p1 { id=1, futureLinkId=f1 }, p2 { id=2, futureLinkId=f1 }` , the output should be `Map { f1 - { id1, id2 } }`

Comment: What does `Map { f1 - { id1, id2 } }` mean?  A `Map` in Java needs to have a key type, which would be `String` here, and a value type, which you're not telling us.

Comment: In any event, the solution will probably involve using [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-).

Comment: @ajb f1 of datatype string, is the key of the Map and values is Collection of strings is the ids of placements that have same future link id, in this example f1.

Comment: @San82 Note that there's no way to access either ID, given the class as you've defined it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually quite simple, despite the convoluted solutions others have offered:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = placements.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Placement::getFutureLinkId, mapping(Placement::getId, toList())));
```

Comment: I guess there must be a reason why the other answers are "convoluted" despite they come from people which are probably not that stupid. The reason is that Java collectors are stupidly undiscoverable as they are radically different from usual FP style collection APIs. First time I see this `mapping` thing, good to know. I find them not flexible at all. Normally you would expect to call all the methods on the top level, but in this API the `collect` on its own can become overly complicated and contain too much logic

Answer (score 0):

You can simply group by `futureLinkId` and then map the values to `id`. One way to write it:

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = Stream.of(new Placement("id1", "f1"), new Placement("id2", "f1"))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Placement::getFutureLinkId))
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(Placement::getId).collect(Collectors.toList())));
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
{f1=[id1, id2]}
```

To make it look nicer, I propose writing two helpers:

```
public static <K, V, N> Map<K, N> mapValues(Map<K, V> map, Function<V, N> mapper) {
    return map.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, mapper.compose(Map.Entry::getValue)));
}

public static <T, R> List<R> map(List<T> list, Function<T, R> mapper) {
    return list.stream().map(mapper).collect(toList());
}
```

and then

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = Stream.of(new Placement("id1", "f1"), new Placement("id2", "f1")).collect(
    collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Placement::getFutureLinkId),
                      res -> mapValues(res, list -> map(list, Placement::getId))));

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: This answer is definitely correct, so if you want to downvote it add a comment first :)

Comment: Not the downvoter, but correctness is not the only reason someone might downvote an answer.

Comment: @shmosel that's precisely why a comment is required to downvote a correct answer. If the answer is just plain wrong, nobody will blame the downvoter for not leaving a comment, but when it's correct... it's not constructive at all to just downvote

Answer (score 0):

Using the [three-argument `toMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) is one way to accomplish what you need.  (`groupingBy` appears to be another, but I'm not as familiar with that method.)

For `toMap`, you need a function that maps your `Placement` to a key; a function that maps your `Placement` to a value, which in this case will need to be a **set** of values; and finally a function that will merge two values together if they have the same key.  Something like

```
Map<String,HashSet<String>> result =
    placements.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap
             (placement -> placement.futureLinkId,
              placement -> new HashSet(Collections.singleton(placement.id)),
              (s1, s2) -> { HashSet<String> result = new HashSet<>(s1);
                            result.add(s2);
                            return result; }));
```

**Note:** I haven't tested this.  It's possible that this could work without copying `s1` if the stream is a sequential stream.

Comment: Java collectors are so bad, I think this is a perfect illustration of this. Your code is simpler than mine, while I'm using the method which is made for this very purpose. However, you do create quite a lot of objects. A helper for constructing mutable singletons would make this better. They should have taken the example of Scala collection API, which is far more powerful and beautiful (however, a lot of it is due to Scala-specific features)

Comment: use placements.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(placement.id,Collectors.toSet()));