# Converting String Collection to a Map with input as the key mapper

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Here's an example:

```
Map<String, Student> getStudentsById(Collection<String> ids) {

  return ids.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(<id-here>, id -> new Student(id))

}
```

I'm not sure how to use `Collectors.toMap`, so that `key` is the stream element (here in case the ID), and `value` is some object constructed from the `key`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a Collection to Map<String,Collection<String>> using java 8 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947983/convert-a-collection-to-mapstring-collectionstring-using-java-8-streams)

Comment: @SebastiánLópez No it's not. This question is about using the same input argument as the key mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `String` and a `Student` to `Collectors.toMap()`, when you should be passing a `Function<? super String,? extends String>` and a `Function<? super String,? extends Student>`.

It should be:

```
Map<String, Student> idToStudent = ids.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), id -> new Student(id)));
```